# how to show an element on hover over another element using css/Extjs

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I'm using extjs for my application. I want to show a setting icon which is a `span` wrapped inside the `div` when I hover over a container. here is the code:

```
<div class="cont">
  <span class="icon"></span>
</div>
```

I tried using the css way to handle the hover state:

css:

```
.cont:hover .icon{
    color: #000000;
}
.icon{
     background-image: url(icon.png) !important;
    background-position: 0px -3px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But the code above does not quite work for me. Is there something i'm doing wrong in the css or a better way in extjs/js that would apply the hover as expected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.cont {
    color: #00FF00;
}
.cont:hover {
    color: #000000;
}
.cont:hover .icon{
    display: block;
}
.icon{
    display: none;
    background-image: url(icon.png) !important;
    background-position: 0px -3px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Banzay: Thanks for the answer, it works for the icon to show up on hover, however the other styling related to the cont: "color: #000000;" does not work, i.e the cont does not change its color to black on hover. any clue?

Comment: attribute `color` affects on text color inside a div. Maybe you mentioned background color? if you want to change color visibly, you should first define text color for unhovered element and it should be different of color for hover. Do you really want such behavior? I've changed an answer. If you want change color of background, you should define `background-color:`

Answer (score 3):

```css
.cont{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:lightgray;
  border-radius:10px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  position:relative;
  color:white;
  }
.icon{
  background-image: url('http://www.chaosads.ph/images/icons2/wrench-screwdriver.png');
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position:absolute;
  right:5px;
  top:5px;
  visibility:hidden;
}

.cont:hover .icon{
  visibility:visible;
}
.cont:hover{
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <span class="icon"></span>
  textexttext
</div>
```